# Draw vertical lines is not possible in paint inside view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In my android application i have a `set of fields in scroll view`. I have one LinearLayout (view) for put signature in that field i am able draw in horizontal not able to draw vertical, when `vertical draw it scrolls the layout`.The below image the top of the view (Black Lines it show dot when vertical draw) shows the error. How to solve this one.[image]

coding:

```
view = mAttesterView;
LinearLayout attestert;
mAttesterView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
attestert.addView(mAttesterView, new     LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mAttesterView.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid scrolling while you drag to draw your onTouch() should return false to consume the touch event.